# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'validSqaures' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, chess

I'm trying to follow a python tutorial on chess, but when i run the function to check for Checkmates and possible moves, I get the following error:

```
  File "d:\Coding\Projects\Chess\stuff\ChessEngine.py", line 86, in getValidMoves
    if not (moves[i].endRow, moves[i].endCol) in validSqaures:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'validSqaures' referenced before assignment
```

This is the code I used for the function

```
    def getValidMoves(self):
        moves = []
        self.inCheck, self.pins, self.checks = self.checkForPinsAndChecks()
        if self.whiteToMove:
            kingRow = self.whiteKingLocation[0]
            kingCol = self.whiteKingLocation[1]
        else:
            kingRow = self.blackKingLocation[0]
            kingCol = self.blackKingLocation[1]
        if self.inCheck:
            if len(self.checks) == 1: #Only 1 piece checking the King
                moves = self.getAllPossibleMoves()
                check = self.checks[0]
                checkRow = check[0]
                checkCol = check[1]
                pieceChecking = self.board[checkRow][checkCol]
                validSquares = [] #Sqaures pieces can move to
                if pieceChecking[1] == "N":
                    validSqaures = [(checkRow, checkCol)]
                else:
                    for i in range(1, 8):
                        validSquare = (kingRow + check[2] * i, kingCol + check[3] * i)
                        validSquares.append(validSquare)
                        if validSquares[0] == checkRow and validSquares[1] == checkCol:
                            break
                for i in range(len(moves) -1 ,-1, -1):
                    if moves[i].pieceMoved[1] != 'K':
                        if len(moves) != 0:
                            if not (moves[i].endRow, moves[i].endCol) in validSqaures:
                                moves.remove(moves[i])
            else: #Double check, King has to move
                self.getKingMoves(kingRow, kingCol, moves)
        else: #Not in check so any move is fine
            moves = self.getAllPossibleMoves()

        if len(moves) == 0:  #either CheckMate or Stalemate
            if self.inCheck == True:
                self.checkMate = True
            else:
                self.staleMate = True
        else:
            self.checkMate = False
            self.staleMate = False
        return moves
```

When I try placing the list validSqaures anywhere else, it just turns blank and doesnt allow me to make anymore moves after putting the opponent king in check.

Comment: check for typos, I could find one in `validSqaures`.

Comment: You got a really nice error message telling you what the issue is: You have not declared that validSquares is when you get to that line. You should be able to figure this out by yourself :)